# WCF client ReaderQuota error despite having set high limits

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

Our app consumes a number of webservices over WCF via basicHttpBinding. The XML messages are often very large (>2mb).

At runtime we are intermittently receiving a deserialization error which appears to be related to ReaderQuotas, which have already been set to Int32.MaxValue.

The head of the stack is (sorry, had to hand type it from an image provided):

```
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: The formatter threw an 
exception while trying to deserializat the message: There was an error while trying to
deserialize parameter [the namespace]. 

The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type 
[a type]. The maximum array length quota (5) or the maximum items in object graph 
quota has been exceeded while reading XML data. These quotas may be increased by
changing the MaxArrayLength property on XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas or the 
MaxItemsInObjectGraph setting. Line 1, position 3645191.
```

The client is configured:

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://someUri/someSvc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SomeSvcBindingConfiguration" contract="SomeSvc" name="SomeSvc" behaviorConfiguration="ClientObjectBehavior" />
</client>

<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientObjectBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="131072"  />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SomeSvcBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:00:15" sendTimeout="00:00:15" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="10485760" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                              maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

...

Could anyone suggest why this exception might still be occurring?

There is no facility to change the binding away from basicHttpBinding, unless it is to some equivalent combination of custom settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number hinted in the exception message - the "(5)" - is actually the running value for the MaxArrayLength setting. Why it is five in this case, I cannot determine without further details.

However, having only a maximum of 131072 objects in the graph might be too small - the `maxItemsInObjectGraph="131072"` setting. Since the error happens at position 3645191 of the xml content, I'd assume that there might be more objects inside that xml than 131072.

Comment: Annoyingly the issue had just vanished and is no longer reproducable, before I even made this change.
You do raise a good point though, so I'm going to award points to you